# jq - How to test for the occurrence of a particular value in a JSON response

Tags: json, jq

Using jq I would like to test for the occurrence of a particular key value in the JSON below, for example that "WARNING" has occurred as a 'severity' value (even once) no matter the amount of objects returned, such that I return a boolean. For simplicity I have 2 objects below, but it could be 2000

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "severity": "WARNING",
      "status": "",
      "time_raised": "1454502910919",
      "data_1": "00000000",
      "data_2": "00000000",
      "data_3": "00000000",
      "register_0": "40000",
      "register_1": "4",
      "register_2": "10",
      "register_3": "0"
    },
    {
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "status": "",
      "time_raised": "1454502840915",
      "data_1": "00000000",
      "data_2": "00000000",
      "data_3": "00000000",
      "register_0": "50000",
      "register_1": "4",
      "register_2": "8",
      "register_3": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

My approach has been to try using the 'contains' filter like so

```
jq .events[]|.severity|contains("WARNING")
```

Which outputs

```
true
false
```

As I want to have a single boolean value returned, I've tried to merge the values into a single string or array before using 'contains', but I can't find a way to do this.

I'd rather keep the logic in jq, so I'm hoping I've missed the wood from the trees and that there is a simple way of doing this in jq.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on your approach, you could, for example, simply write:

```
jq '[.events[]|.severity|contains("WARNING")] | any'
```

Or more succinctly:

```
jq 'any(.events[].severity; contains("WARNING"))'
```

If you want to test for the condition in ANY object, no matter where it is, then consider using walk/1.

Comment: I think the "contains" was introduced on OP's example due to an attempt to merge all `.severity` values into one; `jq '.events | any(.severity == "WARNING")'` should suffice.