# jq - Check if JSON file contains specific value greater than or equal to a defined variable?

Tags: json, bash, shell, continuous-integration, jq

I have a file "results.json"

It looks like this

```
{
    "applicationId" : "application",
    "scanId" : "scanId",
    "policyEvaluationResult" : {
      "alerts" : [ {
        "trigger" : {
          "policyId" : "pid1",
          "policyName" : "Security-High",
          "threatLevel" : 9,
          "policyViolationId" : "pvid1",
        },
        "trigger" : {
          "policyId" : "pid2",
          "policyName" : "Security-Low",
          "threatLevel" : 1,
          "policyViolationId" : "pvid2",
        },
        ...
        }]
    }
}
```

It has multiple "trigger" objects.

I'm trying to write a bash/shell script which checks this file using jq and if it sees that any of the "trigger" objects contain a threatLevel greater than or equal to a variable defined in GitLab CI/CD variables.

If so, it will echo out a failure message and return exit code 1, otherwise echo a success message and return exit code 0.

I don't care about returning any actual values of JSON, I just care about a success/fail outcome.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Any ideas?

At pseudo level I've assumed it's something around the idea of:

```
if (jq 'any(.threatLevel | contains (>=${THRESHOLD_VALUE}))') results.json; then
    echo 'failing pipeline'
    exit 1
else
    echo 'passing pipeline'
    exit 0
fi
```

Am I on the right tracks here?

Comment: "*It has multiple "trigger" objects.*" This is not idiomatic JSON.

Answer (score 2):

> It has multiple "trigger" objects.

This is not idiomatic JSON. Field names are supposed to be unique. Otherwise, JSON processors may collapse them into one, or fail in any another way, not providing you with the expected behavior.

With jq, you could overcome this by having it read and evaluate its input in small pieces using the `--stream` flag, so "past duplicates" would have been processed before the next one would be read.

```bash
if >/dev/null jq --argjson th ${THRESHOLD_VALUE} --stream -en '
  any(inputs | select(.[0][-1] == "threatLevel")[1]; . > $th)' results.json 
then
    echo 'failing pipeline'
    exit 1
else
    echo 'passing pipeline'
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: does a solution like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177992/jq-how-to-test-for-the-occurrence-of-a-particular-value-in-a-json-response work for me in any way?

Comment: @cien I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. The solution from your link uses the same `any` filter as I do, but I can spot three differences: 1) You want to perform a numeric range check ("greater than or equal to"), so it's `. > $th`, not `contains("…")`. 2) Since we're using `--stream` (for reasons explained in the answer) which creates a stream of inputs while you only want a single output, the context inside `any` is `inputs` (with `-n`), not `.`. 3) The use of `-e` and `>/dev/null` let you interpret jq's result as condition in the shell's `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the contains filter is incorrect. You should use the comparison operator ">=" directly instead of "contains".

Here's a revised version:

```
if jq '[.policyEvaluationResult.alerts[] | select(.trigger.threatLevel >= env.THRESHOLD_VALUE)] | length > 0' results.json >/dev/null; then
    echo 'failing pipeline'
    exit 1
else
    echo 'passing pipeline'
    exit 0
fi
```

I hope this helps!